Blazor Application issues after deploying to production environment. Getting Long Polling error with _framework/Blazer.server.js
I am using Blazor App. I have created the project and deployed to lower environments and it is working fine. Also in production environment with default domain it is working but after doing the front door configuration I am getting error. I am not able to redirect or unable to perform any click functionality. Means the @code{} part is not working.
Error I am getting inside _framework/blazer.server.js I have tried all the possible ways but not able to fix it

I have tried with enable the Web Socket. So with Default domain it is working fine but again with Front door URL it is giving the error.
Is there any possible way to fix this in Blazor?

Unless you use the Azure SignalR service it is not going to work as Front Door does not support web sockets. see https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/c8b1d257-8a26-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0789

Do we have any other option in Blazor application, like I don't want to use SignalR Service?

If you have multiple servers, please try to enable ARR. 

I have deployed a sample Blazor web app and configured the webapp to Front door.
Below method worked for me.
Created FrontDoor resource and mapped the web app.
selected Web app URL in Origin host name.


Note :- after deploying the front door mapped to webapp it takes around 20-30 min to able to get the web app to work in FrontDoor endpoint. if you try to access before it it gives 404 error as your screenshot.

OUTPUT:
My main webapp URL

I am also able to navigate to different pages using click and also able to increase counter by clicking it



